# "Button up" vs. "button down"

Tags: meaning, differences, phrasal-verbs

As it pertains to a dress shirt, which is the correct usage or do these terms have different meanings?

Comment: Do any of these references help? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="button+up"+"button+down"

Comment: What is the purpose of Stack Exchange if not to be an authority on questions like this?

Comment: It's an authority on what can't be conclusively answered elsewhere. You haven't even shown that you've done any research whatsoever.

Comment: To elaborate on Andrew's comment, English.SE is for expert-level Q&A. We would love you to join the [ELL](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners) proposal which is intended to help English language learners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *button up* a shirt and *button down* its collar if it comes with a *button-down* collar.

Comment: +1 Button-down shirt is frequently misused to mean any shirt with buttons to close it in the front - coleopterist has it right here in that button-down is specifically shirts that have buttons on the points of the collar.